# Copy cell and paste to web form

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create an order-tracking macro that does the following after I have selected a specific cell:

1. Opens the order tracking webpage, e.g. FedEx shipment tracking
2. Enters the value of a selected cell in my Excel spreadsheet into the appropriate search box on the webpage
3. Clicks submit

I'm working in Excel 2010 off of a sample code I found on another forum. The code accomplishes everything EXCEPT pasting the value of a GIVEN cell. I can assign a numerical value or specific cell value to be entered, but I need a universal macro that I can use for any given cell.

I tried using some basic copy paste functions with the active cell. I managed to select and copy the active cell, but not to paste it into the search box.

Here is the code with problem sections identified.

```
Dim IE As Object

Sub submitFeedback3()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "TrackingWebsite"

    Application.StatusBar = "Submitting"
    ' Wait while IE loading...
    While IE.Busy
        DoEvents
        ActiveCell.Select
        Selection.Copy
    Wend
    ' **********************************************************************
    delay 1
        IE.Document.getElementById("receipt").Click
    delay 1
        IE.Document.getElementById("receipt").Paste
    delay 2
        IE.Document.getElementById("submit").Click
    '**********************************************************************

End Sub

Private Sub delay(seconds As Long)
    Dim endTime As Date
    endTime = DateAdd("s", seconds, Now())
    Do While Now() < endTime
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

When I tried copy/paste code, I used the following underneath DoEvents:

```
ActiveCell.Select
Selection.Copy
```

Comment: what are you talking about? at least what area of software development does this relate to? what is a "cell"? what is "submit"?

Comment: Program is Excel 2010. The submit tag refers to the submit button on the website after the data is pasted.

Comment: `IE.Document.getElementById("appReceiptNum").value = ActiveCell.Value`

Comment: Tim Williams, this is the answer. Thank you! Don't know how to ID your comment as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
IE.Document.getElementById("appReceiptNum").Click 
delay 1
IE.Document.getElementById("appReceiptNum").Paste
```

works for me, on a different site of course.

If it works for you too, make sure to upvote and click the check mark next to this answer!

Comment: After you added the URL to your answer, I looked at the HTML and there are no elements with id="appReceiptNum". There are two elements with name="appReceiptNum", however one of them has id="receipt". Try IE.Document.getElementById("receipt").Paste first and if that doesn't work, try my old answer with the click and the delay but with "receipt" as the id.

Comment: Thank you for circling back to this question. I made the switch, although the ID didn't seem to be the issue. For example, regardless of appReceiptNum or receipt, if I use the line IE.Document.getElementById("whatever").Value = 35, it will input 35. So the target in either case is what I want, but it won't complete the paste function. I think that maybe, being so unexperienced, I'm probably botching the copy paste code. I am using ActiveCell.Select and Selection.Copy. Every time I attempt to run the code, it takes me back to the .Paste line as the problem.

Comment: FYI, Tim Williams above has an answer that works. Still curious as to why the paste function didn't work, but my macro works now. Thank you for your patient help!

Comment: It could have not been selecting the element correctly or been picking the wrong cell.